# Does an If-else boolean expression (&&) increment a variable outside the if-else statements even if one of the expressions are false?

Tags: java

I am doing exercises in my Java Programming book and I came across this:

Suppose that `x` is 1. What is `x` after the evaluation of the following expression?

**A)**

```
(x >= 1) && (x++ > 1)
```

**B)**

```
(x > 1) && (x++ > 1)
```

I understand **B)** because it tests `(x > 1)` first which is false, so it does not test `(x++ > 1)` and therefore doesn't increment `x`.

However, on **A)** `(x >= 1)` is true so it goes to `(x++ > 1)` to test it as well, but `(x++ > 1)` is false. Does this mean that even though it's false, the variable `x = 1` is still being incremented because the expression `(x++ > 1)` was executed?

Comment: Why don't you put `System.out.println(x)` after each (not part of the then clause though so it always happens) to see for yourself? :) Seems like an easy thing to investigate. Next try with `&` instead and look up short circuit evaluation.

Comment: You're right I did put system.out.println(x) after the if else statement that I made for it, I didn't realize I could've resolved my own question there, I was just trying to wrap my head around why it would still increment it when the boolean expression is false.

Answer (score 4):

A) x >= 1 is true and x++ > 1 is false, but x will become 2

Answer (score 1):

To be able to evaluate if x++ is inferior to 1, it needs to evaluate the expression x++, so this seems reasonable, yes. If the expression to evaluate has side effects, they will be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Without evaluation of expression ,any one cant find the result.So your answer is **Yes**,because your expression (x++ > 1) was executed.

Answer (score 0):

these conditions in java are shortfail, meaning only the minimum number of conditions needed are evaluated. in B.) the first condition is false, the operator is && so the entire expression is false anyway. no need to execute the second.

in A.) the first expression is true, so the second one has to be executed to determine the result of the entire expression.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a postfix increment operator, that means it will increment the value of your variable after the expression is evaluated. if you do:

```
if ((x >= 1) && (++x > 1)) {
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

That would be true because I use the prefix increment operator (first increment then evaluate).

Answer (score -1):

(x++ > 1) is almost equal to  (x=(x+1) > 1). The difference is that x is incremented after testing (x > 1) of initial value.
So, it doesn't matter wether the result of testing is true or false, x will be incremeted in both cases.

Comment: the statement ``(x++ > 1) is almast equal to (x=(x+1) > 1)`` is wrong. ``x++`` is not the same as ``x=(x+1)``, you would have to use ``++x`` for that.

Comment: I didn't say that x++ is the same as x=x+1 and used word "almost" with an explanation of difference.

Comment: But in this case it does make a difference because if you used ``x=x+1`` instead of ``x++``, the whole condition would be true.

Comment: I should have used quotations in my post to avoid misunderstanding. I answered the question "even though it's false, the variable x = 1 is still being incremented because the expression (x++ > 1) was executed?". It's about `why x=2 after expression` and not `what is the result of the expression itself`. And in this sense my answer is correct. Anyway, thanks for an amendment.